# .htaccess How to Exclude One Site From SSL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I'm trying to exclude one site from using SSL, but I can't seem to get the directive right.  I want all my AddOn domains to use SSL except example.com. (because StartSSL is difficult to get along with)

```
# Enable https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:443%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule !^example.com(/|$) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:443%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do will not work. The SSL handshake is initialized *before* any request data is sent to the server, therefore, you're going to get a certificate exception if someone goes to `https://example.com` no matter what you do.

If the certificate exception isn't your concern, then you need to match against the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

then if you need:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond ^{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```